How to read nullable string from httpResponseMessage
We have an api method that can return a null value. It returns its like this:
 var formattedValue= null;
 return Ok(formattedValue);

Then on the client we parse the response like this:
 // Check if it's null
 var result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 if (result == null)
 {
     return null;
 }

however the ReadAsStringAsync() returns an empty string by default.
I can't find a way to check if the content is completely empty ie null.

There are Headers which are associated with the HttpResponseMessage

like Allow, Age, RetryAfter, etc.

There are other Headers which are associated with the HttpContent

like Content-Range, Content-Length, Content-Type, etc.

For more details please check this post.

Gladly it is quite easy to fetch the Content-Length through the HttpContent:
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://postman-echo.com/time/now");
var length = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength; // 29, because the body is not empty

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://postman-echo.com/patch");
var length = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength; // 0, because the body is empty

So, you can branch based on the ContentLength
if (httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength > 0)
{
    ...
}


On the client side, you can use the following code to parse the response:
// Check if it's null
var result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    return null;
}

In this case, ReadAsStringAsync() will return an empty string instead of null. To ensure the content is completely empty, i.e., null, you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) to check.
